# Cmake adding a source folder to xcode without compiling the sources inside

Tags: c++, xcode, visual-studio, cmake

I have a project that I am porting to cmake. The architecture of the sources is as follow:

```
src
 |- FolderA
     |-fileAa.cpp
     |-fileAb.cpp
     ...
 |- fileA.cpp
 |-CMakeLists.txt
 ...
```

The file `fileA.cpp` is as follow:

```cpp
#include <FolderA/fileAa.cpp>
#include <FolderA/fileAb.cpp>

//etc
```

My `CMakeFiles.txt` is as follow (the files from `FolderA` **ARE NOT** included in the `add_library` function)

```
#...
add_library(... fileA.cpp ...)
#...
```

And it works well. When I tried to build the library, if I modify any files inside `FolderA`, only the file `fileA.cpp` is rebuilt and the library is remade.

However, when I generate my project for Xcode, the files inside FolderA are not shown. Is there a way to tell cmake that I want it to include the files inside `FolderA` in my Xcode project (and any other supported IDE) but without adding them to the list of files to compile for the `add_library` function?

I tried to set the property of the files in `FolderA` as HEADER and still include them in `add_library` (as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20007840/adding-files-to-cmake-but-not-compiling-them)) and it sort of worked, but in Xcode the files were displayed in a flat hierarchy and I would like to keep the same structure:

What I want in Xcode:

```
|-FolderA
   |-fileAa.cpp
   |-fileAb.cpp
     ...
|- fileA.cpp
```

What I have in Xcode:

```
|-fileAa.cpp
|-fileAb.cpp
|-fileA.cpp
...
```

I there a way to tell cmake to include a folder and its content to the project generated for an IDE, without adding the files I want to the list of files to compile ?

Comment: try [`source_group`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/source_group.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem.

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31652255/source-group-cmake-command-isnt-working) I need to use the files in a target for [`source_group`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20007840/adding-files-to-cmake-but-not-compiling-them) to work. I used the trick that I [mentionned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20007840/adding-files-to-cmake-but-not-compiling-them) of setting the sources of `FolderA` as header files and it worked perfectly:

```
file(GLOB COMPILED_SOURCES "*.cpp")
file(GLOB FOLDERA_SOURCES "FolderA/*.cpp")

set_source_files_properties(${FOLDERA_SOURCES} PROPERTIES HEADER_FILES_ONLY TRUE)

source_group(TREE ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src FILES ${COMPILED_SOURCES} ${FOLDERA_SOURCES})

#...

<any function that create a target>(... ${COMPILED_SOURCES} ${FOLDERA_SOURCES} ... )

#...
```